# Kotlin reflection on inbuilt classes

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I am trying to read the "value" field of a String in Kotlin. I am not very familiar with reflection in Kotlin, so I can't get it to work. This is what I have:

```
var str: String = "Some string"

val field = String::class.java.getDeclaredField("value")
field.isAccessible = true

println(field) // This prints "private final char[] java.lang.String.value"

println(field.get(str)) // This prints [C@66d3c617
```

When trying to cast char[] to Array, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [C cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Character;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a good hint when you `println(field)`. `[C` is actually a character array. You can get the value like this: `field.get(str) as CharArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but you can try this.

```
val value = (field.get(str) as ByteArray).toString(Charset.defaultCharset())
println(value)
```

In my env, the field is a ByteArray so I casted it to a ByteArray and get a printable version. In your case, a simple CharArray should suffice.

Comment: Ohhh, that now makes sense. I tried casting it to Array<Char>, apparently it tried to cast it to a character and then make an array from it or something. Casting it to CharArray worked perfectly. I had no idea that these two are different, thank you for pointing that out.